# Jest react testing: Check state after delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm really confused trying to create test with the help of Jest documentation https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/timer-mocks.html#content

I'm trying to check a state when container mounts and then few seconds later, after I have manually set values in the state (using setTimeout()).

I have a function inside Main's componentDidMount like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setStateAfterDelay();
}
```

And what the function does is:

```
setStateAfterDelay = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ fruits: ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'vodka', 'kiwi'] });
    }, 1500);
}
```

I achieved the first part with:

```
const component = mount(<Main />);
expect(component.state().fruits).toEqual(null);
```

But I have no clue how to check the state again after, lets say 2000ms?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I haven't really tested this code. But, something similar to this should work I think.

```
const fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'vodka', 'kiwi'];

it('mock setTimeout test', () => {
 jest.useFakeTimers();
 setTimeout(() => {
   expect(component.state().fruits).toEqual(fruits);
 }, 1500);
 jest.runAllTimers();
});
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work good! I thought that there was some crazy syntax with unit-testing to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: does this expect really runs? I dont see debug pointer hitting here but my test case going green.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Where are you mounting?

Comment: Because of setTimeout this test wont run but it wont fail also and u see green in test coverage

Answer (score 143):

while jest can run async code easily, you can use promise and setTimeout combination to wait a bit. For example this code will wait for 2 real seconds (if want to [mock time](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks) check jest docs):

```
await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 2000));
```

Full sample test. Don't forget to add `async` flag before the callback function:

```
test('some test title', async () => {
  const foo = true;
  await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 2000));
  expect(foo).toBeDefined();
});
```

Also, keep in mind that default "timeout" is 5 seconds (5000ms). If your test may run longer, you can add `jest.setTimeout(30000);` above the `test()`. 30000 will make sure to not timeout for 30 seconds. You can add any number you need. Full example with setTimeout:

```
jest.setTimeout(30000);

test('some test title', async () => {
  const foo = true;
  await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 2000));
  expect(foo).toBeDefined();
});
```

You can add timeout in jest config too. Here are [config docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration)

Comment: whats the difference to FakeTimers?

Comment: FakeTimers, as name hints, are fake timers. setTimeout will wait for real seconds. Read the docs here: https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks

Comment: I followed this approach with React component with `useState`. Testing-library warned me to use `act(...)` and I did `let timeout = null; await act(async () => { await new Promise((r) => { timeout = setTimeout(r, 2000) }) });`. Then I need to use `useEffect(()=> { return () => { cleanTimeout(timeout) } }, [timeout])` to solve all warnings.

Comment: Any time I use this, even with 1ms, I get a timeout. Any idea why?

Comment: IMO, if you know that the result won't be there for at least 2 seconds, useFakeTimers() is better solution since you know when to check. Instead of wasting time in your test waiting. All unit tests should run fast, why wait?

Comment: Your tests should never "just wait" if it's a unit test: that causes longer test times for no benefit. `jest.useFakeTimers()` with `jest.runAllTimers()` or `jest.advanceTimersByTime(2000)` is the better solution for moving the js clock forward without introducing actual wait time in the test.

Comment: @Akrikos that's true if test is pure and has no side effects or dependencies on some 3rd parties which has their own clocks. Yes, test should be pure w/o such dependencies, but there are tricky situations sometimes.

Comment: @LukasLiesis Fair that sometimes it's complicated. So "never" is too absolute a statement. Reason I made that comment is that your answer is above others due to votes and yours handles the edge case where someone actually needs to wait real time. I see other comments to the same effect, so maybe my comment wasn't even needed. Were I in your place, I'd modify my answer to note that your solution is not for normal usage and is not good unless there's an actual need to wait real time. If possible, let's not confuse folks newer to testing.

Comment: @Akrikos updated with link to mock time docs. Yes, i agree waiting real time is not ideal but in some cases it's needed. Of course tests should be pure functions and not have side effects but stuff do happen and usually i needed myself real time wait, as always it depends on situation what's "normal usage". in any case, added link to mock time too.

Answer (score 19):

You don't need to delay your tests, simply calling `jest.runAllTimers()` before asserting, will work.

```
const fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'vodka', 'kiwi'];

it('initializes the fruits state', () => {
 jest.useFakeTimers();
 jest.runAllTimers();
 expect(component.state().fruits).toEqual(fruits);
});
```

You could also call `useFakeTimers()` in a `beforeEach` if you are going to test multiple times and also `runAllTimers()` could be inside another `beforeEach` so you don't repeat yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is question about how to check something after 20 seconds. But this might be also an indicator that you don't want to test 20 seconds, since what's important sometimes is whether certain action has been performed with the right inputs. In this case, you could restructure your code a bit so that you can pass in a dispatch function. For instance

```
    function abc() {
        return dispatch => {
            return Promise.then(res => {})  // this would take 20 seconds
        }
    }
```

Because `dispatch` is passed in, therefore you can easily use the following in the testing code.

```
    const dispatch = Jest.fn()
    abc(dispatch)
    expect(dispatch).toBeCalled()
```

Of course the assumption is that you do not care about if it's 20 seconds, instead you care more about the workflow process.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this for a while because questions/answers about this problem are often unprecise.

In the case where you are running jest with `jest.useFakeTimers()`, you have then have two types of time:

- **Real time** (wall clock), that one can't be faked.
- **Fake time** (mocked) that is resulting from the jest call to `useFakeTimers`.

In this case, doing something "after a delay" isn't that clear. Are we talking about a **real delay**, or a **fake delay**?

### Advancing fake time

This is the easier part it has been answered in many [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52177631/jest-timer-and-promise-dont-work-well-settimeout-and-async-function?rq=3) and [github issues](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/2157), for example, patching calls to `advanceTimersByTime`:

```
export async function advanceTimersByTime(msToRun: number) {
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(msToRun);
    await flushPromises();
}

function flushPromises() {
    return new Promise(jest.requireActual('timers').setImmediate);
}
```

Which can then be used to check if a long lasting task inside your app managed to perform correctly:

```
describe('Tests', () => {
    it('async test', async () => {
        startLongTask();
        await advanceTimersByTime(10_MINUTES);
        // Assert everything went according to specifications
    });
});
```

### Advancing real time (when using fake timers)

The problem arise when you want to advance real time after you called `jest.useFakeTimers()`. I've tried many approaches, here is the one that worked for me.

In my use case (testing [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) based scheduler) I had no need for `setInterval` to be mocked by jest, therefore, I could simply tell jest to not patch it:

```
jest.useFakeTimers({
    doNotFake: ['nextTick', 'setImmediate', 'setInterval'],
});
```

Remarak, using `nextTick` seems to be required ([otherwise tests will timeout](https://github.com/nock/nock/issues/2200)).

Using this, `setInterval` is now based on real time, which will allow us to define an `elapseRealTime` function using it:

```
export async function elapseRealTime(ms: number) {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
        const intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
            resolve();
            clearInterval(intervalId); // mimic setTimeout
        }, ms);
    });
}
```

This sounds dumb, but it works. Now we can use `elapseRealTime` in a test to advance real time.

```
describe('Tests', () => {
    it('async test', async () => {
        startBackgroundTask();
        await advanceTimersByTime(10_MINUTES);
        // Eventhough fake time now advanced 10 minutes, the background task
        // had no time to be executed if its not part of our app
        // (it is using real time and is unaware of our fake timers)
        await elapseRealTime(10_MS);
        // Now the background task had 10 milliseconds to perform some
        // work.
    });
});
```

#### If you need to mock `setIntervall` in your tests

In the case where you need `setIntervall` to be mocked, an alternative solution (that I don't like that much) is to not mock `Date`:

```
jest.useFakeTimers({
    doNotFake: ['nextTick', 'setImmediate', 'Date'],
});
```

And [use an active loop that regularly check the current time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17936490/1720199). In our case, this can then be used to advance real time:

```
function elapseRealTime(ms: number) {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const then = now + ms;
    while(new Date().getTime() < then){ 
        /* Do nothing */ 
    }
}
```

Since this one is synchronous, it will lock every other test out of the event loop (so it will cost you CPU time and make your test suite run for longer). That also mean you need to call it without `await`:

```
describe('Tests', () => {
    it('async test', async () => {
        startBackgroundTask();
        await advanceTimersByTime(10_MINUTES);
        elapseRealTime(10_MS);
    });
});
```

### Why would you need both types of delays

You might need to wait for a **fake delay** if you are testing so internal application time-related events (a `cron` scheduling a given task after a delay for example).

But you might also be interested in **real delay** for example to give enough time for another application (or a database/sensor/...) to achieve a task related to the test you are running (integration tests). In my use case I needed another app to trigger web hooks calls.