# Jest: Timer and Promise don't work well. (setTimeout and async function)

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

Any ideas on this code

```
jest.useFakeTimers() 

it('simpleTimer', async () => {
  async function simpleTimer(callback) {
    await callback()    // LINE-A without await here, test works as expected.
    setTimeout(() => {
      simpleTimer(callback)
    }, 1000)
  }

  const callback = jest.fn()
  await simpleTimer(callback)
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(8000)
  expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(9)
}
```

```

Failed with

```
Expected mock function to have been called nine times, but it was called two times.
```

However, If I remove `await` from LINE-A, the test passes.

Does Promise and Timer not work well?

I think the reason maybe jest is waiting for second promise to resolve.

Comment: This has always been easy with Sinon's fake-timers. Just do `clock.tickAsync(10000` and it will ensure promises are run. With version 29.5 Jest got this ability too, as it uses Sinon's implementation under the hood, so now just do:
`await jest.advanceTimersByTimeAsync(10000)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Jest [**v29.5.0**](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#2950) You could use [**jest.advanceTimersByTimeAsync(msToRun)**](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestadvancetimersbytimeasyncmstorun)

> Asynchronous equivalent of jest.advanceTimersByTime(msToRun). It allows any scheduled promise callbacks to execute before running the timers.

```
...
await jest.advanceTimersByTimeAsync(1000);
expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled
```

Answer (score 190):

Yes, you're on the right track.

---

### **What happens**

`await simpleTimer(callback)` will wait for the Promise returned by `simpleTimer()` to resolve so `callback()` gets called the first time and `setTimeout()` also gets called.  `jest.useFakeTimers()` [replaced `setTimeout()` with a mock](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/790abe71b9e342170c06a9b75783d929cdd2bb89/packages/jest-util/src/fake_timers.js#L341-L353) so the mock records that it was called with `[ () => { simpleTimer(callback) }, 1000 ]`.

`jest.advanceTimersByTime(8000)` runs `() => { simpleTimer(callback) }` (since 1000 < 8000) which calls `setTimer(callback)` which calls `callback()` the second time and returns the Promise created by `await`.  `setTimeout()` does not run a second time since the rest of `setTimer(callback)` [is queued in the `PromiseJobs` queue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) and has not had a chance to run.

`expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(9)` fails reporting that `callback()` was only called twice.

---

### **Additional Information**

This is a good question.  It draws attention to some unique characteristics of JavaScript and how it works under the hood.

**Message Queue**

JavaScript uses [a message queue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Queue).  Each message is [run to completion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Run-to-completion) before the runtime returns to the queue to retrieve the next message.  Functions like `setTimeout()` [add messages to the queue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Adding_messages).

**Job Queues**

[ES6 introduces `Job Queues`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) and one of the required job queues is `PromiseJobs` which handles "Jobs that are responses to the settlement of a Promise".  Any jobs in this queue run *after the current message completes and before the next message begins*. 
 `then()` queues a job in `PromiseJobs` when the Promise it is called on resolves.

**async / await**

`async / await` [is just syntactic sugar over promises and generators](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#async-function-definitions-awaited-fulfilled).  `async` always returns a Promise and `await` essentially wraps the rest of the function in a `then` callback attached to the Promise it is given.

**Timer Mocks**

[Timer Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks) work by [replacing functions like `setTimeout()` with mocks](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/790abe71b9e342170c06a9b75783d929cdd2bb89/packages/jest-util/src/fake_timers.js#L341-L353) when `jest.useFakeTimers()` is called.  These mocks record the arguments they were called with.  Then when [`jest.advanceTimersByTime()`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/790abe71b9e342170c06a9b75783d929cdd2bb89/packages/jest-util/src/fake_timers.js#L260-L294) is called a loop runs that synchronously calls any callbacks that would have been scheduled in the elapsed time, including any that get added while running the callbacks.

In other words, `setTimeout()` normally queues messages that must wait until the current message completes before they can run.  Timer Mocks allow the callbacks to be run synchronously within the current message.

Here is an example that demonstrates the above information:

```js
jest.useFakeTimers();

test('execution order', async () => {
  const order = [];
  order.push('1');
  setTimeout(() => { order.push('6'); }, 0);
  const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    order.push('2');
    resolve();
  }).then(() => {
    order.push('4');
  });
  order.push('3');
  await promise;
  order.push('5');
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(0);
  expect(order).toEqual([ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' ]);
});
```

---

### **How to get Timer Mocks and Promises to play nice**

Timer Mocks will execute the callbacks synchronously, but those callbacks may cause jobs to be queued in `PromiseJobs`.

Fortunately it is actually quite easy to let all pending jobs in `PromiseJobs` run within an `async` test, all you need to do is call `await Promise.resolve()`.  This will essentially queue the remainder of the test at the end of the `PromiseJobs` queue and let everything already in the queue run first.

With that in mind, here is a working version of the test:

```js
jest.useFakeTimers() 

it('simpleTimer', async () => {
  async function simpleTimer(callback) {
    await callback();
    setTimeout(() => {
      simpleTimer(callback);
    }, 1000);
  }

  const callback = jest.fn();
  await simpleTimer(callback);
  for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
    await Promise.resolve(); // allow any pending jobs in the PromiseJobs queue to run
  }
  expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(9);  // SUCCESS
});
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks Brian. Also some articles refer to JavaScript `message queue` and the `job queue` as the `macro tasks` and `micro tasks`, just to avoid confusion.

Comment: specifically, this worked for me `await Promise.resolve(); // allow any pending jobs in the PromiseJobs queue to run`, thank you!

Comment: This seems to be the best answer on the topic of mixing promises with Jest fake timers, but I don't understand it at all, this stuff doesn't make any sense to me. Anyone has more resources to help me understand? Jest docs handle promises and time separately but I need to test a mixed case..

Comment: Excellent answer - didn't expect to learn so much through this "bug", thanks for taking the time.

Also you can use await jest.advanceTimersByTimeAsync for this now

Answer (score 73):

[Brian Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10149510/brian-adams)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52196951) is spot on.

But calling `await Promise.resolve()` only seems to resolve one pending promise.

In the real world, testing functions having multiple asynchronous calls would be painful if we have to call this expression over and over again per iteration.

Instead, if your function has multiple `await`s it's easier to do this:

1. Create this function somewhere

   > Jest < v27

   ```js
   function flushPromises() {
     return new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
   }
   ```

   > Jest >= v27

   ```js
   function flushPromises() {
     return new Promise(resolve => 
       jest.requireActual('timers').setImmediate(resolve)
     );
   }
   ```
2. Now call `await flushPromises()` wherever you would have otherwise called multiple `await Promise.resolve()`s

More details on [this](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2157) GitHub issue.

Comment: For Jest >= v27:
`function flushPromises() { return new Promise(jest.requireActual("timers").setImmediate)}`

[credit](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2157#issuecomment-897935688)

Comment: Actually for Jest >= v27 the correct function is:
`function flushPromises() {   new Promise(resolve => jest.requireActual('timers').setImmediate(resolve));}`

Comment: Jest 26.6, this is not worked for `jest.useFakeTimers('modern')`, but worked for `jest.useFakeTimers('legacy')`. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126786/jest-fake-timers-with-promises/63296414#63296414) .

Comment: worked like cream, thank you so much, to you and Brian!!

Comment: yes, you must do that in 2022 to migrate to react-scripts v5

Comment: Nice! this cover any combination promises, in my case I have 1 promise resolved and 1 reject. using this function working well !!

Answer (score 4):

There is a use case I just couldn't find a solution:

```js
function action(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    let poll
    (function run(){
      callAPI().then(function(resp){
        if (resp.completed) {
          resolve(response)
          return
        }
        poll = setTimeout(run, 100)
      })
    })()
  })
}
```

And the test looks like:

```js
jest.useFakeTimers()
const promise = action()
// jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000) // this won't work because the timer is not created
await expect(promise).resolves.toEqual(({completed:true})
// jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000) // this won't work either because the promise will never resolve
```

Basically the action won't resolve unless the timer advances. Feels like a circular dependency here: promise need timer to advance to resolve, fake timer need promise to resolve to advance.

Comment: Found this workaround, seems to be the only stable working one: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7151#issuecomment-463370069

Comment: I had exactly the same issue with very similar code. I got it to work by doing `await Promise.resolve(); jest.runAllTimers(); await Promise.resolve();` which gets the code under test to putting the first `setTimeout` onto the queue. Then you can advance timers as normal to perform your test.

Comment: @RobinElvin Can you show me your complete working code with that trick? I'm already stuck for hours with pretty much the same polling-style code. Much appreciated :)

Comment: @GlennMohammad I can't seem to find that code any more. But essentially you use `await Promise.resolve();` in your test to yield to other code so that it can process the queues. It helps to know the exact order of timeouts and promises so you can orchestrate your test. In my example I yielded to let the pending promise resolve and then was able to run pending timers which in turn produced another promise which can be 'flushed' by awaiting again.

Comment: @RobinElvin Thank you so much for your effort. Based on the insights from you, I managed to make it work last night (actually it was 2:30 AM ) by using the same construct. Since I cannot really determine when I have to "kick-in" the first `await Promise.resolve()` to do the yielding in my poll function, I have to do it in a `while` loop like the one in the link pointed by @nemo. Plus, it was also problematic for me when using `nock` at the same time. Here's the snippet that might be useful for future readers: https://gist.github.com/dwiyatci/740a52a08eb6147baa1f0be9b4f38785 

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on the same issue and ended up using [`@sinonjs/fake-timers`](https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers) directly, since it provides `clock.tickAsync()` function, which according to the docs:

> The tickAsync() will also break the event loop, allowing any scheduled promise callbacks to execute before running the timers.

The working example now becomes:

```
const FakeTimers = require('@sinonjs/fake-timers');
const clock = FakeTimers.install()

it('simpleTimer', async () => {
    async function simpleTimer(callback) {
        await callback()
        setTimeout(() => {
        simpleTimer(callback)
        }, 1000)
    }

    const callback = jest.fn()
    await simpleTimer(callback)
    await clock.tickAsync(8000)
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(9) // SUCCESS \o/
});
```

Comment: Glad I read down to this answer. Do you know if there's any problem with using this library directly? It's a lot simpler than the other work arounds.

Comment: I haven't stumbled on any, and I used this library directly for all tests where I need to manipulate time. My suggestion is to just avoid mixing this and jest's wrapper in the same test file.

Answer (score 1):

The above was really helpful! For those who are trying to do this with React hooks(!) the following code worked for us:

```js
// hook
export const useApi = () => {
  const apis = useCallback(
    async () => {
      await Promise.all([
        new Promise((resolve) => {
          api().then(resolve);
        }),
        new Promise((resolve) => {
          return setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
          }, 10000);
        }),
      ]);
    },
    [],
  );
  return [apis];
}

// test
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
function flushPromises() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setImmediate(resolve))
}

it('tests useApi', async () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useApi());
  api.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve());
  await act(async () => {
    const promise = result.current[0]()
    await flushPromises()
    jest.runAllTimers()

    return promise
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use my own fake timer in complex tests.

```
export const useCustomTimer = () => {

    var time = 0;
    var timers: {callback: () => void, ms: number}[] = [];

    const setCustomTimer = (callback: () => void, ms: number = 0) => {
        if(ms<=time){
            callback();
            return;
        }
        timers.push({callback, ms})
        timers.sort((a,b) => a.ms - b.ms);
    }

    const advanceTimersByTime = (ms: number) => {
        time += ms;
        timers = timers.reduce((acc, val) => {
          if(val.ms<=time) {
            val.callback();
          }
          else acc.push(val);
          return acc;
        }, []);
    }

    const advanceTimersToNextTimer = () => {
        if(timers.length) advanceTimersByTime(timers[0].ms - time);
    }

    return {
        setCustomTimer,
        advanceTimersByTime,
        advanceTimersToNextTimer
    }
}
```

Test:

```
test('should demonstrate custom timer', async () => {
      const {setCustomTimer, advanceTimersByTime, advanceTimersToNextTimer} = useCustomTimer();

      const values = [];
      values.push(0);

      const promiseAll = Promise.all([
          new Promise<void>((res) => setCustomTimer(() => { values.push(2); res(); }, 5)),
          new Promise<void>((res) => setCustomTimer(() => { values.push(4); res(); }, 12)),
          new Promise<void>((res) => setCustomTimer(() => { values.push(6); res(); }, 20)),
      ])
      .then(() => {
          values.push(7);
      })

      values.push(1);

      advanceTimersToNextTimer(); // OR advanceTimersByTime(5);

      values.push(3);

      advanceTimersToNextTimer(); // OR advanceTimersByTime(7);

      values.push(5);

      advanceTimersToNextTimer(); // OR advanceTimersByTime(8);

      await promiseAll;

      values.push(8);

      expect(values).toEqual([ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a retry with timeouts pattern: awaiting a promise with a timeout several times.
I ended up with the following solution, based on Brian Adams' answer, if it can be of any help to anyone.

```js
/**
 * Execute an async function while flushing timers in a loop as long as the promise is still pending
 *
 * @param fn an async function
 * @returns fn return type
 *
 * @see {@link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52177631/jest-timer-and-promise-dont-work-well-settimeout-and-async-function}
 */
const executeWhileFlushingPromisesAndTimers = async <F extends () => Promise<any>>(
  fn: F,
  maxLoopNb = 100,
): Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<F>>> => {
  let pending = true
  let result: Awaited<ReturnType<F>>
  let error: Error
  let times = 0

  fn()
    .then((res) => {
      result = res
      pending = false
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      error = err
    })
    .finally(() => {
      pending = false
    })

  while (pending && times < maxLoopNb) {
    await Promise.resolve()
    jest.runAllTimers()
    await new Promise((resolve) => (jest.requireActual('timers') as any).setTimeout(resolve, 0))
    times++
  }

  if (pending) {
    throw new Error(
      `From executeFlushingPromisesAndTimers - promise still pending after ${maxLoopNb} (maxLoopNb) jest.runAllTimes. Make sure to mock the asynchronous code.`,
    )
  }
  if (error) {
    throw error
  }
  return result
}

test('async retry with timeout', () => {
  expect(await executeWhileFlushingPromisesAndTimers(initSW)).toBe(false)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Jest v28+, simply passing `advanceTimers` option as in:

```js
jest.useFakeTimers({advanceTimers: true})
```

will do to make fake timers and pending promises work in harmony :-)

From the docs (https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestusefaketimersfaketimersconfig):

```
type FakeTimersConfig = {
  /**
   * If set to `true` all timers will be advanced automatically by 20 milliseconds
   * every 20 milliseconds. A custom time delta may be provided by passing a number.
   * The default is `false`.
   */
  advanceTimers?: boolean | number;
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some further clarification to [Molten Ice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/679285/molten-ice)'s comments on Promise.resolve():

Promise.resolve() will clear the (FIFO) microtask queue of work, but will not cause execution of any callbacks created by *promise chaining* with *.then*. That is because those callbacks will be placed on the microtask queue *after* the promise they are called on settles, and *after* execution of the synchronous code following `await Promise.resolve()`.

This behaviour can be demonstrated as follows:

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(1)).then(() => console.log(2)).then(() => console.log(3)).then(() => console.log(4));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(5)).then(() => console.log(6)).then(() => console.log(7)).then(() => console.log(8));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(9)).then(() => console.log(10)).then(() => console.log(11)).then(() => console.log(12));
```

will output

```
1
5
9
2
6
10
3
7
11
4
8
12
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34816941)