# Testing a Recursive polling function with jest and fake timers

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have created a polling service which recursively calls an api and on success of the api if certain conditions are met, keeps polling again.

```
/**
   * start a timer with the interval specified by the user || default interval
   * we are using setTimeout and not setinterval because a slow back end server might take more time than our interval time and that would lead to
   * a queue of ajax requests with no response at all.
   * -----------------------------------------
   * This function would call the api first time and only on the success response of the api we would poll again after the interval
   */
  runPolling() {
    const { url, onSuccess, onFailure, interval } = this.config;
    const _this = this;
    this.poll = setTimeout(() => {
      /* onSuccess would be handled by the user of service which would either return true or false
      * true - This means we need to continue polling
      * false - This means we need to stop polling
      */
      api
        .request(url)
        .then(response => {
          console.log('I was called', response);
          onSuccess(response);
        })
        .then(continuePolling => {
          _this.isPolling && continuePolling ? _this.runPolling() : _this.stopPolling();
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (_this.config.shouldRetry && _this.config.retryCount > 0) {
            onFailure && onFailure(error);
            _this.config.retryCount--;
            _this.runPolling();
          } else {
            onFailure && onFailure(error);
            _this.stopPolling();
          }
        });
    }, interval);
  }
```

While trying to write the test cases for it, I am not very sure as to how can simulate fake timers and the axios api response.

This is what I have so far

```
import PollingService from '../PollingService';
import { statusAwaitingProduct } from '@src/__mock_data__/getSessionStatus';
import mockAxios from 'axios';

describe('timer events for runPoll', () => {
    let PollingObject,
    pollingInterval = 3000,
    url = '/session/status',
    onSuccess = jest.fn(() => {
      return false;
    });
    beforeAll(() => {
      PollingObject = new PollingService({
        url: url,
        interval: pollingInterval,
        onSuccess: onSuccess
      });
    });
    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.useFakeTimers();
    });
    test('runPolling should be called recursively when onSuccess returns true', async () => {
      expect.assertions(1);
      const mockedRunPolling = jest.spyOn(PollingObject, 'runPolling');
      const mockedOnSuccess = jest.spyOn(PollingObject.config, 'onSuccess');
      mockAxios.request.mockImplementation(
        () =>
          new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve(statusAwaitingProduct);
          })
      );

      PollingObject.startPolling();
      expect(mockedRunPolling).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mockAxios.request).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
      expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.any(Function), pollingInterval);

      jest.runAllTimers();
      expect(mockAxios.request).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mockedOnSuccess).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(PollingObject.isPolling).toBeTruthy();
      expect(mockedRunPolling).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    });
  });
});
```

Here even though mockedOnsuccess is called but jest expect call fails saying it was called 0 times instead being called 1times.

Can someone please help?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Issue

There might be other issues with your test as well, but I will address the specific question you asked about `expect(mockedOnSuccess).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);` failing with `0 times`:

`jest.runAllTimers` will synchronously run any pending timer callbacks until there are no more left.  This will execute the anonymous function scheduled with `setTimeout` within `runPolling`.  When the anonymous function executes it will call `api.request(url)` but *that is all that will happen*.  Everything else in the anonymous function is contained within `then` callbacks that [get queued in the `PromiseJobs` Jobs Queue introduced with ES6](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues).  None of those jobs will have executed by the time `jest.runAllTimers` returns and the test continues.

`expect(mockAxios.request).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);` then passes since `api.request(url)` has executed.

`expect(mockedOnSuccess).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);` then fails since the `then` callback that would have called it is still in the `PromiseJobs` queue and hasn't executed yet.

### Solution

The solution is to make sure the jobs queued in `PromiseJobs` have a chance to run before asserting that `mockedOnSuccess` was called.

Fortunately, it is very easy to allow any pending jobs in `PromiseJobs` to run within an `async` test in `Jest`, just call `await Promise.resolve();`.  This essentially queues the rest of the test at the end of `PromiseJobs` and allows any pending jobs in the queue to execute first:

```jsx
test('runPolling should be called recursively when onSuccess returns true', async () => {
  ...
  jest.runAllTimers();
  await Promise.resolve();  // allow any pending jobs in PromiseJobs to execute
  expect(mockAxios.request).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(mockedOnSuccess).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // SUCCESS
  ...
}
```

Note that ideally an asynchronous function will return a Promise that a test can then wait for.  In your case you have a callback scheduled with `setTimeout` so there isn't a way to return a Promise for the test to wait on.

Also note that you have multiple chained `then` callbacks so you may need to wait for the pending jobs in `PromiseJobs` multiple times during your test.

More details about how fake timers and Promises interact [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52196951/10149510).

Comment: Thank you @brian-lives-outdoors. I kind of followed the similar approach and it worked for me. But what I did was exactly what you mentioned in this answer.

Thank you for that link. I will go through it and read more about promises and fake timers.

Just one more question, if I have multiple then block all chained, for now I have to write multiple Promise.resolve to reach all those then blocks. For example if I have three then chained, to reach the third then I have to do Promise.resolve three times. Is there a better way to do this or is this right?

Comment: You can await multiple `PromiseJobs` cycles on the same line by chaining `.then()` calls to the end of the `Promise.resolve`.  For example, to wait three cycles do `await Promise.resolve().then().then();`.  Once again, returning Promises and awaiting them directly is always ideal, but for situations where that is not possible this approach will work.

Comment: need your help again. I have replaced axios with fetch and struggling with the same issue again. onSuccess is not getting called. Any way I can contact you other than SO, twitter may be? Thank you

Comment: @VivekN just create a new SO question and I'll take a look