# How do I test promise delays with jest?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, es6-promise, babel-jest

Here's my code which I use to delay process (for backoff)

```
export function promiseDelay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

I would want to test it but I'm not able to. I tried working with fakeTimers but my test never ends.

```
test('promiseDelay delays for 1s', async (done) => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    Promise.resolve().then(() => jest.advanceTimersByTime(100));
    await promiseDelay(100);
  });
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`promiseDelay` returns a `Promise` that resolves after `ms` so call a `spy` in `then` and test to see if the `spy` has been called after different intervals:

```js
describe('promiseDelay', () => {

  beforeEach(() => { jest.useFakeTimers(); });
  afterEach(() => { jest.useRealTimers(); });

  test('should not resolve until timeout has elapsed', async () => {
    const spy = jest.fn();
    promiseDelay(100).then(spy);  // <= resolve after 100ms

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(20);  // <= advance less than 100ms
    await Promise.resolve();  // let any pending callbacks in PromiseJobs run
    expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(80);  // <= advance the rest of the time
    await Promise.resolve();  // let any pending callbacks in PromiseJobs run
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
  });

});
```

Note that test code is synchronous and [Timer Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks) make `setTimeout` synchronous but `then` [queues a callback in `PromiseJobs`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) so any queued callbacks need to be allowed to run before testing if the `spy` has been called.

This can be done by using an `async` test function and calling `await` on a resolved `Promise` which effectively queues the rest of the test at the end of `PromiseJobs` allowing any pending callbacks to run before the test continues.

Additional information about how promises and fake timers interact is available in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52196951/10149510).

Comment: @thegeekajay The test in the question provides the argument `done` to the test function but never calls it, that's the reason that particular test never finishes: ["Jest will also wait if you provide an argument to the test function, usually called done"](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testname-fn-timeout)

Comment: Thanks, i figured that out and fixed it. but the test 'should not resolve if < 100ms' is always failing. coz the spy function was called.

Comment: @BrianAdams, why the test does not work without `await Promise.resolve();`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to return the promise from the function like

```
test('promiseDelay delays for 1s',() => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => jest.advanceTimersByTime(100));
});
```

and then spy the setTimeout to be called once.