# Testing sleep function from JavaScript using Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have this function:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds);
  });
}
```

Basically this function delays logic, e.g.:

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds);
  });
}

async function delayedGreeting() {
  console.log("Hello");
  
  await sleep(2000); //will wait 2 Seconds and after that will display the next code
  
  console.log("World!");
}

delayedGreeting();
```

I want to test the `sleep` function using Jest.

```
test('test', async () => {
  await sleep(2000);
});
```

I don't know how to test this function.

Comment: You will probably want to record the time before and after the `await sleep` and assert that the difference in time falls within acceptable ranges. If it falls in acceptable ranges.

Comment: Please do research before asking, Asking: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52673682/3001761 (not even the first time it's asked _today_: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70079395/3001761).