# Jest unit test - How do I call through async function in a setTimeout repeating function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

UPDATE: Safe to say this is basically a duplicate of [Jest: Timer and Promise don't work well. (setTimeout and async function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52177631/jest-timer-and-promise-dont-work-well-settimeout-and-async-function/52196951#52196951)

---

I have a function that repeats itself after performing an asynchronous function. I want to verify that `jest.advanceTimersOnTime(5000)` continues to yield `expect(doAsyncStuff).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(X);`.

I observe that we can reach the call to repeat the function but it does not "go through" when asking jest to advance timers.  It does work when you remove the async function preceding it. So it sounds like I have to get doAsyncStuff to "call through" or resolve some pending promise here?

### Function

```
function repeatMe() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        doAsyncStuff.then((response) => {
            if (response) {
                console.log("I get here!");
                repeatMe();
            }
        })
    }, 5000);
}
```

### Test

```
jest.useFakeTimers();

let doAsyncStuff = jest.spyOn(updater, 'doAsyncStuff');
doAsyncStuff.mockResolvedValue(true);

repeatMe();

jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);
expect(doAsyncStuff).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);
expect(doAsyncStuff).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2); // Failed?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So it sounds like I have to...resolve some pending promise here?

Yes, exactly.

---

The short answer is that a `Promise` callback gets queued in [PromiseJobs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) by the `then` chained to the `Promise` returned by `doAsyncStuff`, and the way the test is written, **that callback never has a chance to run until the test is already over**.

To fix it, give the `Promise` callbacks a chance to run during your test:

updater.js

```
export const doAsyncStuff = async () => { };
```

code.js

```
import { doAsyncStuff } from './updater';

export function repeatMe() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    doAsyncStuff().then((response) => {
      if (response) {
        console.log("I get here!");
        repeatMe();
      }
    })
  }, 5000);
}
```

code.test.js

```
import * as updater from './updater';
import { repeatMe } from './code';

test('repeatMe', async () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();

  let doAsyncStuff = jest.spyOn(updater, 'doAsyncStuff');
  doAsyncStuff.mockResolvedValue(true);

  repeatMe();

  jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);
  expect(doAsyncStuff).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  // Success!

  await Promise.resolve();  // let callbacks in PromiseJobs run

  jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);
  expect(doAsyncStuff).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);  // Success!

  await Promise.resolve();  // let callbacks in PromiseJobs run

  jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);
  expect(doAsyncStuff).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);  // Success!

  // ... and so on ...
});
```

---

The complete details of exactly what happens and why can be found in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52196951/10149510)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Jest troubleshooting references this issue: `we have set the definition to happen asynchronously on the next tick of the event loop`.  I guess this applies to  events within the live code too, not just the written tests.

Doing `jest.runAllTimers()` will set things into an endless loop.

Adding `jest.runAllTicks()` will advance the tick so the above tests now work.

I'm still confused but I guess this is the answer.

```
jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);
jest.runAllTicks();
expect(doAsyncStuff).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);
jest.runAllTicks();
expect(doAsyncStuff).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting#defining-tests

---

Also required for this to work is to mock the implementation of doAsyncStuff because whatever async stuff inside doAsyncStuff also I think gets queued into the tick events.

```
            doAsyncStuff.mockImplementation(() => {
                return new Promise.resolve();
            });
```