# Testing that promise resolved not until timeout sinon chai

Tags: javascript, promise, sinon, chai

We have a simple wait method leveraging promises in our node app

```
exports.wait = (timeout) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve()
    }, timeout)
  });
};
```

We tried to test this behavior using sinon and chai.

We managed to get a proper assertion using chai-as-promised but it only check the promise resolves, without being able for us to test the real behavior:

- when passing a value of 100 ms to the wait method
- we expect the promise not to resolve at 99ms
- we expect the promise to resolve at 100ms

The combination of promise with timers is really what gets us headaches.

Here is our last try setup:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const sinon = require('sinon');
chai.use(require('sinon-chai'));
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

const wait = require('./wait').wait;

var clock;

before(() => {
  clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
});

after(() => {
  clock.restore();
})

it('should not resolve until given time', (done) => {
  const promise = wait(100);
  let fulfilled = false;

  promise.then(() => {
    fulfilled = true;
    done();
  });

  clock.tick(99);
  expect(fulfilled).to.be.false;
  clock.tick(2);
  expect(fulfilled).to.be.true;
});
```

But `fulfilled` is never flipped to true, or at least we cannot read it.

> AssertionError: expected false to be true

How then mix timers with promise testing under chai - sinon to asset properly our timed resolve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test the code from the question like this:

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const sinon = require('sinon');

const wait = require('./wait').wait;

var clock;

before(() => {
  clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
});

after(() => {
  clock.restore();
})

it('should not resolve until given time', async () => {  // <= async
  const promise = wait(100);
  let fulfilled = false;

  promise.then(() => {
    fulfilled = true;
    done();
  });

  clock.tick(99);
  await Promise.resolve();  // let any pending Promise callbacks run
  expect(fulfilled).to.be.false;  // Success!
  clock.tick(2);
  await Promise.resolve();  // let any pending Promise callbacks run
  expect(fulfilled).to.be.true;  // Success!
});
```

---

**Details**

[Fake timers](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.3.1/fake-timers/) turn callbacks scheduled with `setTimeout` into synchronous calls.

`Promise` callbacks, on the other hand, get queued in the [PromiseJobs queue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) when the `Promise` resolves, and don't run until *after the current executing message has completed*.

In this case, the currently running message is *the test*, so the `then` callback that sets `fulfilled` to `true` doesn't run until **after** the test has completed.

You can use an `async` test function and call `await Promise.resolve();` at any point where you want to pause the currently running message and allow any queued `Promise` callbacks to run.

For additional details about using Fake Timers with `Promises` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52196951/10149510) which uses `Jest`, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: didn't know about the queue mechanism, thanks for your help it works great

Comment: Just stumbled on the same issue and thought why the accepted isn't working for me.. turned out, as I had a promise inside a promise, I needed to use 2x the await Promise.resolve(). Doesn't seem too applicable in my case, since the code starts to look weird, but maybe someone finds this useful.