# Sinon clock.tick doesn't advance time for setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

I am writing a test for an `async` function which performs a series of tasks and at one point waits for 60 seconds before doing some more tasks. I am trying to use `sinon.useFakeTimers()` to skip those 60 seconds so that I can test the logic after the delay.

foo.js

```
module.exports.foo = async f => {
  // ... more code ...
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 60000);
  });
  // ... more code ...
  f();
  // ... more code ...
};
```

test-foo.js

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

const { foo } = require('./foo');

describe('Module Foo ', function() {
  it('call function after 1 minute', function() {
    var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    const bar = sinon.stub();

    foo(bar);
    expect(bar.called).to.be.false;
    clock.tick(100000);
    expect(bar.called).to.be.true; // this one fails
  });
});
```

I tried putting `sinon.useFakeTimers();` in various other places, but the Promise doesn't resolve and the stub I pass into `foo` doesn't get called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make your test function `async` and `await` a resolved `Promise` after advancing your clock to give the `Promise` callback queued by the `await` in `foo` a chance to run before doing your assertion:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

const { foo } = require('./foo');

describe('Module Foo ', function() {
  it('call function after 1 minute', async function() {  // <= async test function
    var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    const bar = sinon.stub();

    foo(bar);
    expect(bar.called).to.be.false;  // Success!
    clock.tick(100000);
    await Promise.resolve();  // <= give queued Promise callbacks a chance to run
    expect(bar.called).to.be.true;  // Success!
  });
});
```

For complete details see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52196951/10149510) which uses `Jest` and `Jest` [timer mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks) but the concepts are the same and also apply to `Mocha` and `Sinon` [fake timers](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.3.2/fake-timers/).