# How to use SinonJs to spy on number of async calls without await

Tags: javascript, async-await, mocha.js, chai, sinon

In the following example, I've two functions doTask and doSubTask. Both are async, but due to some business need, I need to fire & forget doSubTask twice with different parameters

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const doTask = async (taskId) => {
  await wait(taskId)
  doSubTask(taskId * 3)
  doSubTask(taskId * 5)
  console.log('end task :' + taskId)
}

const doSubTask = async (subTaskId) => {
  await wait(subTaskId)
  console.log('end subTask :' + subTaskId)
}

doTask(2000)
```

How can I write a test case for doTask, and assert that doSubTask has been called twice?

---

Here's a code sample, you can run it on [runkit.com](https://runkit.com/mahmoud-samy/601d47c0784dbc0013f771bc)

```
require("@fatso83/mini-mocha").install()

const sinon = require("sinon@7.5.0")
const referee = require("@sinonjs/referee")
const chai = require('chai')
chai.use(require('sinon-chai'))
const expect = chai.expect

const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const doTask = async (taskId) => {
  await wait(taskId)
  doSubTask(taskId * 3)
  doSubTask(taskId * 5)
  console.log('end task :' + taskId)
}

const doSubTask = async (subTaskId) => {
  await wait(subTaskId)
  console.log('end subTask :' + subTaskId)
}

const app = {
  doTask,
  doSubTask,
}

describe("stub", function () {
  it("doSubTask should be called twice", async function () {
    const doSubTaskSpy = sinon.spy(app, 'doSubTask')
    
    await doTask(2000)
    
    expect(doSubTaskSpy).to.be.calledTwice()
  })
})
```

Output from the above code is:

```
stub
end task :2000
❌ doSubTask should be called twice (Failed with: "expecte…e been called exactly twice, but it was called 0 times")
end subTask :6000
end subTask :10000
```

Answer (score 1):

We should use [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) package to require the module and stub `doSubTask` function. Besides, we should use [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55906241/sinon-clock-tick-doesnt-advance-time-for-settimeout) to use fake timers and advance the time when you use `promise` and `setTimeout` together.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
const wait = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const doTask = async (taskId) => {
  await wait(taskId);
  doSubTask(taskId * 3);
  doSubTask(taskId * 5);
  console.log('end task :' + taskId);
};

const doSubTask = async (subTaskId) => {
  await wait(subTaskId);
  console.log('end subTask :' + subTaskId);
};

const app = {
  doTask,
  doSubTask,
};

module.exports = app;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const rewire = require('rewire');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('stub', function () {
  let clock;
  before(() => {
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
  });
  after(() => {
    clock.restore();
  });
  it('doSubTask should be called twice', async function () {
    const doSubTaskStub = sinon.stub();
    const mod = rewire('./');
    mod.__set__('doSubTask', doSubTaskStub);
    const promise = mod.doTask(2000);
    clock.tick(2010);
    await promise;
    sinon.assert.calledTwice(doSubTaskStub);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(doSubTaskStub, 6000);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(doSubTaskStub, 10000);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  stub
end task :2000
    ✓ doSubTask should be called twice (738ms)


  1 passing (743ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   84.62 |      100 |      75 |   81.82 |                   
 index.js |   84.62 |      100 |      75 |   81.82 | 11-12             
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```