# Even after using jest.useFakeTimers getting timeout error for polling function

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have created below function for polling

```
export const wait = (ms: number): Promise<void> =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));


/**
 *
 * @param {*} fn async function which will return result
 * @param {*} cb callback to verify result for expected result. Return boolean value true to stop polling.
 * @param {*} ms polling time
 * @returns
 */
export async function polling<T>(
  fn: () => Promise<T>,
  cb: (res: T) => boolean,
  ms: number
): Promise<T> {
  try {
    const res = await fn();
    if (cb(res)) {
      return res;
    }
    await wait(ms);
    return polling(fn, cb, ms);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

For which I have written specs as

```
  it('should poll for 5 times', async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    let count = 0;
    const fn = () => {
      count += 1;
      return count;
    };
    const cb = (res) => res === 5;
    const resP = polling(fn, cb, 1);
    jest.runAllTimers();
    const res = await resP;
    jestExpect(res).toBe(6);
  });
```

as shown in the above code I am using jest fakeTimer and still getting the below error
I have also tried keeping `jest.useFakeTimers();` global scope but still getting the same error.

```
● Test Data Science Common Utility functions › should poll 5 times

    : Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

       95 |   });
       96 | 
    >  97 |   it('should poll for 5 times', async () => {
          |   ^
       98 |     jest.useFakeTimers();
       99 |     let count = 0;
      100 |     const fn = () => {
```

I am new to writing the specs, The specs I have written above might be completely wrong. So correct spec for the above polling function will be appreciated.

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52177631/jest-timer-and-promise-dont-work-well-settimeout-and-async-function

Comment: The linked answer is unrelated as it doesn't seems to (really) use fake timers (no timeout even though the provided code does timeout with fake timers). Did you found a solution to your issue? I found several github dissucssions and issues about this problem but none of the solution seems to work for per-test increased timeouts.