# Unexpected behaviour testing React component after delay with Jest/Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a pretty basic React component that displays a sequence of dots for when something is loading, by default it displays up to 3 dots and the dots increment on an interval set within a `componentDidMount` function, resetting at the number of dots. The number of dots and interval can both be overwritten by passing through props. This component is below.

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface Props {
    interval?: number;
    dots?: number;
}

class LoadingDots extends React.Component<Props, object> {
    public static defaultProps: Partial<Props> = {
        interval: 300,
        dots: 3
    };
    interval: any;

    state = {
        frame: 1,
        interval: this.props.interval,
        dots: this.props.dots
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({
                frame: this.state.frame + 1
            });
        }, this.props.interval);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    public render() {
        let dots = this.state.frame % (this.props.dots + 1);
        let text = "";
        while (dots > 0) {
            text += ".";
            dots--;
        }
        return (
                <p className="loadingDots" {...this.props}>{text}</p>
        )
    }
}

export default LoadingDots;
```

The issue I'm now having is testing this component, following the [Jest Documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks) and [Jest react testing: Check state after delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478730/jest-react-testing-check-state-after-delay) I have written the test below to check the correct default number of dots are rendered at the end of the set of frames (would pass with a 200ms delay).

```
test('LoadingDots by default renders with 3 dots', () => {
    var loadingDots = Enzyme.shallow(<LoadingDots interval={100} />);
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    jest.runAllTimers();
    setTimeout(() => {
        expect(loadingDots.find('p').text()).toBe("...")
    }, 300);
});
```

This test passes but shouldn't, it passes regardless of what value I put in the `.ToBe` of `expect(loadingDots.find('p').text()).toBe("...")`.

I've tried rendering the component as `var loadingDots = Enzyme.mount();` and `var loadingDots = Enzyme.render();` but still the same outcome, does anyone see what's going wrong here? How can I get this to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1**

`jest.useFakeTimers()` replaces the timer functions like `setInterval` with timer mocks that track the arguments they were called with.  It needs to be called before your component is created so the `setInterval` call in `componentDidMount` calls the mock instead of the real `setInterval`.

**Issue 2**

`jest.runAllTimers()` attempts to run all timer callbacks until there are none left.  In this case `setInterval` is never cancelled so `jest.runAllTimers` would attempt to run timer callbacks forever and `Jest` would interrupt the test with an error after it runs 100000 callbacks.

The correct way to advance time in this scenario is to use [`jest.advanceTimersByTime`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestadvancetimersbytimemstorun) (or the alias `jest.runTimersToTime` for `Jest` < 22).

**Issue 3**

`setTimeout` is not needed since [Timer Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks) execute synchronously.

---

Here is an updated test for your component:

```tsx
test('LoadingDots by default renders with 3 dots', () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();  // replace timer functions like setInterval with timer mocks
  const dots = 3;
  const interval = 100;
  var loadingDots = Enzyme.shallow(<LoadingDots interval={interval} />);
  for(let i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    const expectedDots = i % (dots + 1);
    expect(loadingDots.find('p').first().text()).toBe('.'.repeat(expectedDots));
    jest.runTimersToTime(interval);  // simulate time passing and run any applicable timer callbacks
  }
  jest.useRealTimers();  // restore timer functions
});
```